# Issues with ASP.NET via Apache/mod_mono on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, asp.net, mono

I run an Ubuntu test server, and my deployment system is also Ubuntu.

I've recently been trying to get ASP.NET to work on my test server so that we can take it live. I managed to get it installed, and configured properly, and my application is installed and running, but I can't get anything to work.

The error I keep receiving is below, if anyone has any clue what might be going on, it would be greatly appreciated.

> Server Error in '/' Application
>
> Standard output has not been redirected or process has not been started.
>
> Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.
>
> Stack Trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Standard output has not been redirected or process has not been started.
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.CancelErrorRead () [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:CancelErrorRead ()
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] 
  at Mono.CSharp.CSharpCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000]
```

> Version information: Mono Version: 2.0.50727.42; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.42
>
> Apache version String: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) mod_mono/2.0 PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch Server at dev Port 80

PS: I had to add three DLL's to the `/bin` directory in my application, copying them from Windows because I couldn't find them in any of Mono's packages. This might or might not be causing problems, I don't know. The list that I had to add is:

- System.Web.Abstractions
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me, YMMV. Another suggestion was to install the mono-devel package.

From [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/running-aspnet-applications-in-debian-and-ubuntu-using-xsp-and-mono.html#comment-2869):

Try:

```
sudo find /usr/bin | grep gmcs
```

If result is NOT

```
/usr/bin/gmcs
/usr/bin/gmcs2
```

Then try:

1. install mono-gmcs package (if only have “/usr/bin/gmcs”)
2. in case you have only “/usr/bin/gmcs2″ make symlink on it named gmcs

   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gmcs2 /usr/bin/gmcs

Restart apache2 or xsp or your web server and check result in browser. I think it would help.

Comment: Why not try `sudo find /usr/bin -name 'gmcs*'` instead?

Comment: Let's not argue semantics. And I didn't write it, I'm simply providing information someone else came up with.

Comment: Even better question, why sudo? /usr/bin will pretty much always be world readable.

Answer (score 0):

I setup my asp.net site blogengine.net (blog.extriko.com) on mono.  I had troubles getting it to run in apache, so I found [this](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI) post using mono-fastcgi-server2 and set it up with fastcgi running on lighttpd.  Works great and lighttpd is super easy to setup.